# How can I profile C# methods per second?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I don't know if the title makes sense, but I am trying to time two different methods and see how many times they execute per second, or say per 10 seconds.

For instance:

```
DividePolygons1(Polygon[] polys)
DividePolygons2(Polygon[] polys)

DividePolygons1 ran:
1642 times per 1 second

DividePolygons2 ran:
1890 times per 1 second
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class will help you here, but be careful to use the results somehow so that the optimizer doesn't eliminate the logic you're trying to measure.

Beyond that, just run the code you're profiling several million times in a loop (adjust the iteration count to make it take between 1 and 30 seconds), then divide the number of iterations by the time taken to get the throughput in executions per second.

Comment: And use a release build and have no debugger attached when starting the program. And better run all of the code once before starting the benchmark so startup effects like JITing aren't measured.

Comment: Don't forget to watch out for locality of reference. It may take longer to divide the same exact polygons if they don't always get created at the same time.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, how do I make sure no debugger is attached? using the release build does this automatically?

Comment: @Conrad Frix, can you please give me more example about this? I am not sure if I know about this case.

Comment: @Joan: Choose "Start without Debugging" from the Visual Studio menu.  Or start from outside VS, e.g. an explorer window or a command prompt.  It has no relation to whether you did a debug or release build.

Comment: @Joan: What Conrad is talking about is that modern processors make a *copy* of a block of memory *on the chip itself* with the optimistic assumption that the memory contents are not going to change on another thread during the processing of the current thread. That copy on the chip is called the "cache". Doing a memory read of something in the cache is potentially hundreds of times faster than doing a memory read of something that "misses" the cache. The details of the size of your array of polys and where it gets allocated can create unexpected huge perf differences.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks Eric, very useful reply. So should I avoid this case to get a more accurate measurement? If so, how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: @Joan: If you're passing the same data into both versions, and doing enough iterations, then the difference ought to (nearly) average out.

Comment: @Joan: it's not something you can easily avoid, and it is difficult to measure without a profiler specifically designed to query the CPU for cache miss statistics. Rather, it's just something to be aware of when profiling. I recently had a situation where allocating *less* memory made my application *slower* because it just so happened that the changes to the allocation strategy caused a different pattern of cache misses. It can be very confusing!

Comment: @Joan: something to particularly keep in mind when working with large arrays is that accessing memory with "good locality" is a big perf win. For example, try making a large 2-d array and profile working with each element with the loop nested: for(rows) { for (columns) { ... } } vs for(columns) { for (rows) { ... } } -- often there is a big difference because one causes a lot of cache misses and the other mostly uses memory that is "close together" and therefore likely to be in the cache already.

Comment: Thanks Ben and Eric, really useful replies. I understand it better now.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

- Start a `Stopwatch`.
- In those functions, I increment a simple variable (long, float, or double, depending on how often you think they'll get called) so it's incremented on each call.
- Call the first function.
- Stop the `Stopwatch` and check the `TotalSeconds` against the variable I've been incrementing.
- Repeat for the second function.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 has a profiler which could determine the exact number of methods calls per time unit.

Comment: Thanks, is it in the pro version? (not ultimate)

Comment: The profiler is available in Premium and Ultimate editions, but not Pro.  See http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products under "Debugging and Diagnostics".